# SVG Snap select a group by it's ID

Tags: javascript, raphael, snap.svg

I'm trying to get an SVG Snap element by it's id. First I create a canvas:

```
 var s = Snap("#svgout"), //creates the canvas
```

Then I cerate a group:

```
            var rect = s.rect(posx, posy, 40, 40, 6).attr({
                fill: "none",
                stroke: "#F44336",
                strokeWidth: 3,
            });

            var group = s.group(rect).attr({
                cursor: "move",
            });
```

and next I get the id of the group that is defaulted by SVG Snap

```
var currGroupId = group.id;
```

Now, when I try to reference my group later in my code and get it by it's id,

```
s.select(currGroupId);
```

I get null. How do I properly select an element by it's id?

Answer (score 0):

select will use a cssSelector, as in container.queryAll.

So I don't think Snap sets an id as an svg attribute (do correct me if I'm wrong). Which means if you want to use select, you may have to manually set it.

Also I susect s.select(id) wouldn't work, I think it would have to be s.select('#'.id) but I may be wrong. If you can get a fiddle up, it will be easier to test.

Answer (score 0):

SnapSVG doesn't automatically set the ID attribute of the group. Instead it adds a field to the object itself. One way of getting around this limitation is to do the following.

```
var s = Snap("#svgout");

var rect = s.rect(posx, posy, 40, 40, 6).attr({
  fill: "none",
  stroke: "#F44336",
  strokeWidth: 3,
});

var group = s.group(rect).attr({
  cursor: "move",
});
```

Explicitly set the ID.

```
group.attr({
  id: group.id
});

var currGroupId = group.id;
```

`select` uses CSS selectors. So we must add a '#' to the start of the ID.

```
s.select("#" + currGroupId);
```

Note: This method has been tested by me using SnapSVG V0.4.1

If this does not work and you are using jQuery. try:

```
$("#"+currGroupId);
```

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work for me. I'm doing exactly what you said and I am getting " Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': '#5772d8baa94c91baaf7038d5' is not a valid selector."

Comment: It works when I do it the jquery way.. with $('#' + currGroupId)

Comment: it worked for me, I was able to run `s.select("#" + currGroupId).attr({ fill: "blue"});` My IDs have always been in the form 'gSiq0kea402' though i.e. 11 characters long. What browser are you using?

Comment: My Id's are similar, I am using chrome.

Comment: This is working for me on `Ubuntu 14.04 - Chrome and Firefox`.